# Questionnaire link on election page links to the questionnaire of the latest election for all elections

Tags: bug, election

Currently, the link to the questionnaire on election page always goes to the latest questionnaire regardless of which election it is.

For example, Movies & TV SE's [second election](https://movies.stackexchange.com/election/2),

[image]

and the [first election](https://movies.stackexchange.com/election/1),

[image]

point to the same questionnaire.

**Is this a bug or intentional?**

It is not only happening on Movies & TV, but on other sites as well.

Comment: [as discussed just now I really get irritated with this issue](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47226386#47226386), they should make every election post individual to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes, it is happening on other sites I tested with. Seems like a bug, as it doesn't make sense to be intentional.